# how to solve spring mvc org.springframework.security error?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, maven-plugin

When i try to add this 2 Dependency in my pom.xml it's give error in              pom.xml file.

1)org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:3.2.8.RELEASE
    2)org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.8.RELEASE

i face this error :

Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE

and

Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE

how can i solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Spring Security is 3.2.5.RELEASE

Do this:

```
<properties>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>
```

Comment: i want use 3.2.8.RELEASE  then

Comment: There's no 3.2.8.RELEASE of Spring Security. It's different than Spring Core or Spring MVC. They have their own version numbers. You can use Spring 3.2.8 with Spring Security 3.2.5